# Need help with curve of intersection

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, parametric

I have $16x^2+y^2=16$ and $x+y+z=7$

I need to find the length of the curve of intersection of these two.

This is what I did:

$$\begin{align}
&x^2+\frac{y^2}{16}=1\\
&x=\cos t\\
&y = 4\sin t\\
&z = 7-\cos t - \sin t
\end{align}$$

so the vector equation is

but it shows that this is not correct, because the plot doesn't work.Please let me know what went wrong. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have

$$ z = 7 - x - y = 7 - \cos t - 4 \sin t.$$

Comment: Yup. You were on the right track, just did something sloppy, @Tmm.

Comment: Thanks, I was in a rush. @Ted Shifrin